# Email verification using php and smtp

Tags: php, mysql, smtp

I am trying to verify the email which is send from the following email id, it was sent to the specific email with an activation link but it can't activate. Here is two page database_connection.php for database connection and active.php for activation.  \
database_connection.php

```
    /*Define constant to connect to database */
    DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'db_user');
    DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'db_password');
    DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
    DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'trqnwr_forum');
    /*Default time zone ,to be able to send mail */
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    /*You might not need this */
    ini_set('SMTP', "mail.myt.mu"); // Overide The Default Php.ini settings for sending mail


    //This is the address that will appear coming from ( Sender )
    define('EMAIL', 'ismaakeel@gmail.com');

  DEFINE('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://www.leedsit.com/reg');


    // Make the connection:
    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        DATABASE_NAME);

    if (!$dbc) {
        trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    ?>
```

active.php

```
<html>
<body><?php
include ('database_connection.php');

if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email']))
{
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 32))//The Activation key will always be 32 since it is MD5 Hash
{
    $key = $_GET['key'];
}


if (isset($email) && isset($key))
{

    // Update the database to set the "activation" field to null

    $query_activate_account = "UPDATE members SET Activation=NULL WHERE(Email ='$email' AND Activation='$key')LIMIT 1";


    $result_activate_account = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_activate_account) ;

    // Print a customized message:
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1)//if update query was successfull
    {
    echo '<div class="success">Your account is now active. You may now <a href="login.php">Log in</a></div>';

    } else
    {
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Oops !Your account could not be activated. Please recheck the link or contact the system administrator.</div>';

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

} else {
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Error Occured .</div>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you nulling the activation code when they go onto the page instead of verifying it?

Comment: exactly, first check whether the activation key associated with the email exists, if exists then set activation null

Comment: its allready done in index.php page

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 if (mysqli_affected_rows($result_activate_account) == 1)
```

Instead of

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1)
```

Problem is that you are not passing the result as resource.

Comment: it doesn't work , it shows mysqli_affected_rows expects paramiter 1 as resource

Comment: is means $result_activate_account is not set properly check your query